# JQUERY animate() in Internet Explorer (11) - absolute object starts from top

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-animate

Problem is that I've a list of elements with an image beside it. If one element is clicked the appropriate image should animate to a certain position and width while all other images are animating to an opacity of 0.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/CzVAa/9/

HTML

```
<div class="arg_selector">
    <input type="hidden" name="helpstatus" value="1" />
    <div>
        <div class="arg_pr">
            <div class="arg_selectheader">
                Products
            </div>
            <ul>

                <li>
                    <div class="arg_pr_img">
                        &nbsp;<img src="http://ftp5.cse-online.de/temp/images/selfline-200.png" alt="Bild SelfLine" border="0" width="100" id="img1" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="arg_pr_item" data-id="1">
                        <p>SelfLine</p>
                    </div>
                    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <div class="arg_pr_img">
                        &nbsp;<img src="http://ftp5.cse-online.de/temp/images/trailedline-200.png" alt="Bild TrailedLine" border="0" width="100" id="img2" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="arg_pr_item" data-id="2">
                        <p>TrailedLine</p>
                    </div>
                    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
                </li>

            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="arg_anf"></div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The images are positioned absolute to make them free placeable.

```
.arg_pr_img img             { position:absolute; z-index:20; }
```

And the animate JS is:

```
var imgPos = (ele.closest("ul").height()/2)-(imgIn.height()/2);
            imgIn.animate({
                width: 180,
                top: imgPos,
                opacity: 1
            }, 1000);
```

This works just fine in Firefox, Chrome, Safari. But if I test that in IE (11) the image jumps to the top of the parent element and starts animating from there instead of its original position.

Hints are very appreciated. Thank u all in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Set position: relative or absolute to parent (for animating elements) element

Comment: Thank you for answering. But this seems not to work. I've set each parent by another upwards to position:relative; but the only change was that the imgage animates static not absolute to its desired location.